# Can two models have two types of relationships through two fields?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm building a chat room application where the two primary models are `User` and `Room`. Now, a user can create new rooms, as well as belong to existing rooms. So I ended up with the following model for rooms:

```
defmodule Elemental.TxChat.Room do
  use Elemental.TxChat.Web, :model

  schema "rooms" do
    field :name, :string
    field :created_at, Ecto.DateTime

    # Foreign key indicating which user created this room
    # One user can create any number of rooms 
    belongs_to :created_by, Elemental.TxChat.User
    field :created_from_app, :integer

    many_to_many :members, Elemental.TxChat.User, join_through: "rooms_users"

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:name, :created_at, :created_by, :created_from_app])
    |> validate_required([:name, :created_at, :created_by, :created_from_app])
  end
end
```

My confusion is, it now looks like there are two kinds of relationships between `User` and `Room`: Many to one, and many to many. A colleague suggested that I remove the `belongs_to` field and replace it with a simple integer field, but then I don't want to lose the benefits of foreign key check at DB level.

How can this situation be resolved?

Comment: Why do you/your colleague want to remove that? It's perfectly fine to have multiple relationships between 2 models in an RDBMS.

Comment: You could let it be two separate relationships, if they mean two different things. You could also add some metadata to the `rooms_users` table, like a `creator` boolean, or some kind of `role` level, containing "creator/admin" or something like that.

Comment: @Dogbert Okay, thanks. He said that it's not the right way to do it. Maybe he too has some confusion. Anyway, I just wanted to check if this approach was sane.

Comment: @Frost Thanks but as of now there are no roles in my system. I guess I'll stick to what I have.

Comment: Your created_at field is made redundant by the use of the `timestamps` macro. You could get rid of it

Comment: @peuh Excellent insight! Thanks for the sharp eyes. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by @Dogbert in the comments, it is perfectly fine to have multiple relationships between two schemas.